# How can I make OSX remember the desktop assignment of different chrome windows

Tags: macos, google-chrome, desktop

Problem: When using google chrome browser (51.0.2704.103) on OSX (10.11.6) I often find myself losing my carefully ordered window placement between my many desktops. This happens if chrome happens to quit, or whenever OSX restarts.
OSX tends to remember desktop allocation per application, but all chrome windows get bundled in the same desktop whenever chrome restarts.

Motivation: This is crucial to me because I alternate different projects and for productivity reasons I have each project on a different desktop.

Comment: Can't be done. It will always return all windows to the same Space at relaunch. 'Fix' would be to use a different browser for each use case.

Comment: @Tetsujin, could you elaborate on why you think this can't be done? Could a chrome extension handle this? Or an OSX native app?

Comment: Spaces simply wants all one app's windows in one Space. I've not seen anything that can break that habit, short of manually hauling them around every time. I organise my workflow to avoid it for that very reason. There may be a 3rd party app, but I don't know of one.

Comment: Possibly, there is a way. Using a combination of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191845/open-application-in-specific-space-through-applescript and native application creator. Google for `nativefier` or `chromium webapp runtime`.

Comment: @Tetsujin iTerm restores windows to correct spaces not mentioning Apple own apps

Comment: iTerm2 is the only app I found that actually remember which desktop its windows were on when you reopen it

Answer (score 19):

**Edit**: This still doesn't COMPLETELY work for me as well: some windows are restored and some are not. The new bug id is [1012034](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1012034).

---

This is being fixed in the latest development version (Chrome 79) as [bug #74812](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=74812#c116).

Though, by default, in compliance with Apple's UI requirements, this feature still won't restore the workspaces if you exited Chrome with Cmd-Q. Quoting `sdy`, the feature author:

> For folks who want Chrome to always restore windows to their original spaces, you can set that by running this command in a terminal window (for Canary, use `com.google.Chrome.canary`):
>
> ```
> defaults write com.google.Chrome NSWindowRestoresWorkspaceAtLaunch -bool YES
> ```
>
> To go back to the default behavior, run:
>
> ```
> defaults delete com.google.Chrome NSWindowRestoresWorkspaceAtLaunch
> ```

Comment: Just tried this on Chrome 79.0.3945.130 official, macOS 10.14.6, and it didn't work at all. Don't think it's ready.

Comment: Works like charme at my M1 Mac - Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102 (arm64), MacOS Monterey 12.2.1

Comment: Worked great on my macbook pro running Catalina 10.15.7 - THANKS SO MUCH - that was driving me nuts - this should be marked as the answer IMO.

Comment: @Victor Sergienko, you say "compliance with Apple's UI requirements". I tried to locate this in Apple's UI requirements but fell short. Where do i find this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"won't restore the workspaces if you exited Chrome with Cmd-Q":_ So then, how am I supposed to exit Chrome while making sure it restores to the correct desktop the next time it launches?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like OSX will open all the windows of an application in the same
desktop space.
You will therefore need to open each window as a separate application instance.

For most applications, but not for Chrome, it is enough to open it via
`open -naF "App Name"`, but for Chrome you must also specify a different
`--user-data-dir` parameter for each instance.
You will need as many temporary directories as the number of instances
that you wish to open.

References :

- [How to open new windows as separate application instances for Chrome, Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230390/how-to-open-new-windows-as-separate-application-instances-for-chrome-terminal)
- [Multiple Instances of Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/yarina.org/dougs-notes/home/mac-os-x/multiple-instances-of-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

I came to this issue as well, this is how I tried to solve this.

1. Right click chrome->options->Assign To (choose none).As shown in the picture down below

[image: snapshot1-chrome]

2. Now you could click the chrome window to another desktop.Then you will see chrome in the second desktop.

[image: snapshot2-desktop]

Comment: This to my understanding assigns the Chrome *application* to a desktop (with all it's windows) rather than a single *Chrome window*.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: What does "None" do? What does "All Desktops" do? Edit: "All Desktops" will make the app (all of its windows) move with you when you move from space to space.