# How to restore Chrome windows to their respective desktops when reopening Chrome on macOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, tabs

I use separate desktops for different projects on my Mac. Inside each desktop, I have a few Chrome windows for web-related work pertaining to that project. When I quit Chrome and reopen it, all previously open Chrome windows across different desktops open up in the first desktop (Desktop 1) while all other desktops have no Chrome windows. As a result, I have to rearrange the Chrome windows by dragging them to their respective desktops each time I quit and reopen Chrome.

As an example, suppose I have two desktops open. Desktop 1 has three Chrome windows and Desktop 2 has four Chrome windows. When I quit Chrome and reopen it, all seven Chrome windows open up in Desktop 1, while Desktop 2 has no Chrome windows.

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically restore Chrome windows to their respective desktops (from the previous Chrome session) when reopening Chrome.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1111535/how-can-i-make-osx-remember-the-desktop-assignment-of-different-chrome-windows Basically, you're trying to fight the way Spaces works. It was never designed to allow any single app to be spread over multiple Spaces.